# st_extract in stars with bilinear = TRUE crashes R on mac with M1 chip

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, r-stars

Apparently the bilinear extraction in `st_extract` from the stars package causes problems on a mac with the M1 chip. Does anybody found the problem and/or has a workaround? The function `st_extract` works perfectly with `bilinear = FALSE`.

```
> library(stars)
Loading required package: abind
Loading required package: sf
Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stars_0.5-6 sf_1.0-8    abind_1.4-5
```

Example:

```
library(stars)

rast <- st_as_stars(volcano)
pts  <- st_point(c(50, 50)) %>% st_sfc() 

st_extract(rast, pts, bilinear = T)
```

Comment: If this is still the case, and if you provide a reproducible example, I can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks! The problem still exists. I added an example that causes R Studio to crash on my M1 MacBook.